# Why do we use functionName: function in javascript return statement

Tags: javascript, function

I am completely new to javascript. I saw the below snippet in a tutorial. But i am not sure why do we use funtionName: function  in return statement.

For example, getID:function()  and setID: function() in the below code. Can anybody explain.

```
function celebrityID () {
    var celebrityID = 999;

    return {
        getID: function ()  {

          return celebrityID;
        },
        setID: function (theNewID)  {

            celebrityID = theNewID;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That's the [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) syntax. It's used to, well, create objects.

Comment: I am not sure what you are confused about. Since, JS has first class functions so functions can be stored in variable and as object properties. And here `celebrityID` function is returning an object with two properties which are functions and can be invoked later. Simple.

Comment: So that in future any celebrity could `get` and `set` the `celebrityID` like so. `var celebrity = celebrityID()` and `celebrity.getID()` or `celebrity.setID(20000)`

Comment: @bugwheels94 :Thank you. It is clear now.

Comment: @Alvaro Gonzalez: Thank you. It is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `celebrityID ()` function you are returning an object, which has two properties those properties are function.

you can call

```
var myVar = new celebrityID();

myVar.getID(); // myVar = 999
```

this like object creation from a class

Answer (score 0):

So they can use it as

```
var cid = celebrityID();
var celbId = cid.getID();
```

If you do not have the return statement the function `getID()` will not be useful and also `celbId` becomes undefined.

If you closely observe, there is no return statement for setter.